# Spinning wheel on Android

Tags: android

I am trying to design a widget which looks like the "spinning wheel" (I am not sure it is appropriate name for it) widget that you can use to set up alarms or counters on the clock app provided with HTC Hero. 
For those who do not know this application, this widget is made up with wheels that you scroll to specify hours, minutes, seconds. 
I think it could be something like a kind of listview with a mask on it that isolate the selected element or a costumized timePicker but I do not manage to implement my widget from them and I did not find any tutorial on this topic.

Is there an easy way to do this based on ListViews?

Anyone has got an idea?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Hey there, there is one project doing this already, downloadable [here](http://code.google.com/p/smooth-wheel/).
And thats not the only project of it's kind. En plus, [here](http://android-devblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/wheel-ui-contol.html) is a tutorial about how to create such a wheel urself.

Cheers,
Ready4Fajir